# How do I authorize users on Telligent Community Server 2008.05 into another site?

Tags: drupal, single-sign-on, telligent

I have a group of users with accounts on a Community Server 2008.5 installation, and I would like them to be able to log in on that site and automatically be logged into a Drupal installation as well (on a separate machine).

I believe I'll be able to figure out the Drupal site using the many external authorization tutorials, but I haven't been able to find any information about the CS 2008.5 side of it. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a single sign-on module that enables authenication across sites, this is an add-on. We have used on asp.net forms authentication, but it looks like you its possible using cookies: http://telligent.com/support//communityserver/community_server_2008/w/cs20085docs/installing-cookie-authentication-extension.aspx

Comment: Hi Mark, it looks to me like that extension allows CS to use another website for its logons. Does it also work in reverse?

Answer (score 1):

CS2008.5 can integrates easily with Microsoft Active Directory as .NET application.
So for drupal you can use LDAP integration - it's for connecting users via Active Directory:
http://drupal.org/project/ldap_integration

If there's already users in AD, and you want to add them automatically to drupal, you need to import them to via http://drupal.org/project/ldap_provisioning